# Convert array elements to suitable json in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have an array of numbers, say [1, 2], I want to convert this to json format as:

```
["id_list":
    [
        {
            "id" : 1
        },

        {
            "id" : 2
        }
    ]
]
```

Can this be done in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
struct Root :Codable {

    let  id_list:[InnerItem]
}

struct InnerItem : Codable {

    var  id:String

}
```

//

```
let arr = [1,2]

let js = Root(id_list:arr.map { InnerItem(id: "\($0)")})

do {

    let en = try JSONEncoder().encode(js)

    let json = String(data: en, encoding:.utf8)!

    print(json)

}
catch {

    print(error)
}
```

//

[image]

Comment: I have to pass this as post parameter, how can i match the format exactly as in the question?

Comment: see edit .......... , also note post body expects data so assign  **en** to it , and if object i converted it to string

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let dic = ["id_list":[["id": "1"], ["id": "2"], ["id": "3"]]]
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(dic) {
        if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(jsonString)
        }
    }
```

your output will be like this

{"id_list":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]}

Answer (score 0):

you may try following simple method with `for each` loop for this:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4]

var str = "[\"id_list\":["
for element in arr {
    str = str + "{\"id\": \(element)},"
}
str.remove(at: str.index(before: str.endIndex))
str = str + "]]";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
["id_list":[{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3},{"id": 4}]]
```

Comment: Why manually create the string when swift has excellent json support?

Comment: Accepted, but using this method you can encode any type when array element is int, float, string.

Comment: So you can when adopting the Codable protocol and this isn't encoding, it is string building.

Comment: OK, to add to this question how to achieve this when let arr = [1,2,3,4] could be of diff types ?

Comment: Have you tried yourself? I mean it is you who are extending the question.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to achieve this more swifty way as suggested by vadian and Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple struct adopting `Codable`

```
struct Ident : Codable {
    let id : Int
}
```

Map the array to struct items

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
let idArray = array.map{ Ident(id:$0) }
```

Then use `JSONEncoder` to create the JSON

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(["id_list" : idArray])
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding:.utf8)!
    print(jsonString) // {"id_list":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]}
} catch { print(error) }
```

Your JSON format is invalid, it's either `{"id_list": ... }` or `[{"id_list": ... }]` but it cannot be `["id_list": ... ]`